# Stamping / Tagging / Branding Object Instances

Tags: .net-4.0, metadata

I have a routine which accepts an object and does some processing on it. The objects may or may-not be mutable.

```
void CommandProcessor(ICommand command) {
    // do a lot of things
}
```

There is a probability that the same command instance loops back in the processor. Things turn nasty when that happens. I want to detect these return visitors and prevent them from being processed. question is how can I do that transparently i.e. without disturbing the object themselves.

**here is what i tried**

- Added a property `Boolean Visited {get, set}` on the `ICommand`.

I dont like this because the logic of one module shows up in other. The `ShutdownCommand` is concerned with shutting down, not with the bookkeeping. Also an `EatIceCreamCommand` may always return `False` in a hope to get more. Some non-mutable objects have outright problems with a setter.

- privately maintain a lookup table of all processed instances. when an object comes first check against the list.

I dont like this either. (1) performance. the lookup table grows large. we need to do liner search to match instances. (2) cant rely on `hashcode`. the object may forge a different hashcode from time to time. (3) keeping the objects in a list prevents them from being garbage collected.

I need a way to put some invisible marker on the instance *(of ICommand)* which only my code can see. currently i dont discriminate between the invocations. just pray the same instances dont come back. does anyone have a better idea to implement this functionality..?

Comment: Can you clarify 'invisible marker on the instance' to mean the instance of the ICommand, or the instance of the owner of 'CommandProcessor'?

Comment: @GarryVass Instance of ICommand. (so that i can detect when it enters again.)

Comment: I would create an internal interface that inherits from ICommand and used for the instances you want, and declare ShutdownCommand from ICommand.  I checked, by the way, if it's possible to play fun and games with custom attributes, but it's not.

Comment: "the object may forge a different hashcode from time to time" - that sounds broken to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet *"the object may forge a different hash code from time to time"* because hash codes are dependent on internal state of that object (based on the value of an instance field or property ). Immutable objects will honor their hash codes but i dot know whether an implementation is immutable or not. it might differ from one implementation to next.

Comment: @inquisitive: Okay, so it's not like they're doing anything *wrong* (which is what "forge" suggested to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can't stop this from happening just logically (try to cut out the loop) I would go for a `HashSet` of commands that you've already seen.

Even if the objects are violating the  contracts of `HashCode` and `Equals` (which I would view as a problem to start with) you can create your own `IEqualityComparer<ICommand>` which uses [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx) to call `Object.GetHashCode` non-virtually. The `Equals` method would just test for reference identity. So your pool would contain distinct instances without caring whether or how the commands override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

That just leaves the problem of accumulating garbage. Assuming you don't have the option of purging the pool periodically, you could use [`WeakReference<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738.aspx) (or the non-generic `WeakReference` class for .NET 4) to avoid retaining objects. You would then find all "dead" weak references every so often to prevent even accumulating those. (Your comparer would actually be an `IEqualityComparer<WeakReference<T>>` in this case, comparing the *targets* of the weak references for identity.)

It's not *particularly* elegant, but I'd argue that's inherent in the design - you need processing a command to change state somewhere, and an immutable object can't change state by definition, so you need the state outside the command. A hash set seems a fairly reasonable approach for that, and hopefully I've made it clear how you can avoid all three of the problems you mentioned.

EDIT: One thing I hadn't considered is that using `WeakReference<T>` makes it hard to remove entries - when the original value is garbage collected, you're not going to be able to find its hash code any more. You may well need to just create a new `HashSet` with the still-alive entries. Or use your own LRU cache, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: thanks. `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode` is a great help. its documentation writes *useful in scenarios where you care about object identity.* Thanks for that. `WeakReference<T>` is in 4.5, but I am stuck with 4.0. So reference accumulation is still a problem. But i can live with something like LRU Cache and delete entries older than say 15 mins.