# use of System.identityHashCode(obj) - when? why?

Tags: java, hashcode

when would be a reasonable time to do line #4 instead of line #3?  Or are they perfectly redundant invokes?

```
1  Object o1 = new Object();

2  

3  int hcObj = o1.hashCode();

4  int hcSys = System.identityHashCode(o1);
```

Comment: Uhm, good question... By the way, both methods return an int, not a long

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes you might want to create a set of distinguishable objects. Some of those objects may be *equal* to each other, but you still want references to all of them... only throwing away genuinely duplicate references. You might do that because the `equals` implementation isn't the one you're interested in (some classes override `equals` when you really don't want them to) or because you're actually just trying to count separate instances etc.

To do that efficiently (i.e. backed by a hash table of some kind) you want a hash code based on identity rather than equality - which is exactly what `identityHashCode` gives you. It's *rarely* useful, but it can still be handy at times.

Comment: In short, what Guava's `Equivalence.identity()` does? But even then, you have `IdentityHash{Map,Set}`

Comment: @fge: `System.identityHashCode` is how all of those data structures are implemented.

Comment: "(some objects implement equals when you really don't want them to)"      Love this part of your answer.  thanks.

Comment: `System.identityHashCode()` returns same value as `java.lang.Object.hashcode()` method?

Comment: @sanbhat: It returns the value that `Object.hashcode` would return *if it's not overridden*.

Comment: @JonSkeet:Why would one need to keep different references for objects having exactly the same state? He could just keep a counter and hold a single reference.Could you please give a specific use case that this makes sense?

Comment: @Cratylus: The objects don't necessarily have exactly the same state. They have state which is equivalent under `equals` - which might not be the kind of equivalence you want to use. As I say, it's very rarely useful, but it can be handy.

Comment: @Cratylus: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069923/stamping-tagging-branding-object-instances for a very recent question along these lines - it's based on .NET rather than Java, but the same ideas apply.

Answer (score 4):

For a plain `Object`, yes, it's redundant. But there are cases where a class might want to use the default `hashCode` implementation (based on reference equality) on an instance of a type that could have overridden `hashCode`.

Grepcode [lists these call sites](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root@jdk%24openjdk@7-b147@java%24lang@System@identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29&start=0&type=method&k=u), namely including [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) amongst others.